# How to load meta tags functions for whole site

Tags: zend-framework

In my site i need to set the meta tags(Meta keywords, meta description) differently for each controller by taking it from Database.

Now i need to write a function that will get the related META contents from DB and set the Meta tags depends upon which controller is loading at that moment

But i couldn't get where i can write the function for it.

I found the helper function headMeta() to set the same from each View file but i ay need to repeat the same db operation in all controller init() function i think.

Can any one help out with the code i have to write in controller and view files Please.....

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, not tested. Please change class names to your namespaces :-)

```
//layout.phtml
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>

//My_Controller_Plugin_HeadMeta.php
class My_Controller_Plugin_HeadMeta extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $controller = $this->getControllerName();
        $db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
        $view = $layout->getView();           

        // do your db stuff here
        // db results
        $results = array();


        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $view->headMeta()->appendName('keywords', $result);
        }
    }   
}

//applications.ini
resources.frontController.plugins.0 = "My_Controller_Plugin_HeadMeta"
```